# Why Pygame's get_at works slow when getting successive pixels?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

While using Version 1, Program runs faster then Version 2.Why ?.

I have use Pygame to implement flood fill ALGO,Pygame's get_at method is used to implement get_pixel method.

Why Pygame's get_at method runs slower when getting successive pixels.?

Version 1:

```
while start < len(to_color):
    # remove a single (x,y) tuple from to_color and call it this_cell.
    # BFS -->Queue
    this_cell = to_color[start]
    start += 1
    # DFS -->Stack
    # this_cell = to_color.pop(-1)

    # get color of removed location.if color is not same as starting color then don't add it to to_color
    **current_color = get_pixel(image, *this_cell)
    if not color_check(original_color, current_color):
        continue**

    # replace that spot with the given color
    set_pixel(image, *this_cell, new_color)

    # add each neighbor to to_color only if location is within limits 
    **for neighbor in get_neighbors(this_cell):
        if boundary_check(neighbor):
            # add each neighbor to to_color
            to_color.append(neighbor)**
```

Version 2:

```
while start < len(to_color):
    # remove a single (x,y) tuple from to_color and call it this_cell.
    # BFS -->Queue
    this_cell = to_color[start]
    start += 1
    # DFS -->Stack
    # this_cell = to_color.pop(-1)

   

    # replace that spot with the given color
    set_pixel(image, *this_cell, new_color)

    # add each neighbor to to_color only if location is within limits 
    **for neighbor in get_neighbors(this_cell):
        current_color = get_pixel(image, *neighbor)
        if boundary_check(neighbor):
             if color_check(original_color, current_color):
        
                 # add each neighbor to to_color
                 to_color.append(neighbor)**
```

I have used Pygame's get_at to implement

`def get_pixel(image, x, y): color = image.get_at((x * SCALE, y * SCALE)) return (color.r, color.g, color.b)`

Answer (score 0):

Pixel operations like [`pygame.Surface.get_at`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) are very slow. In the 2nd version `get_at` is called more often than in the 1st version. Therefore the 2nd version is slower.

It is recommended to use [`pygame.PixelArray`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/pixelarray.html) for operations like this:

```py
pxarray = pygame.PixelArray(image)

for neighbor in get_neighbors(this_cell):
    current_color = pxarray[neighbor[0], neighbor[1]]

    # [...]
```